Get-AzKeyVaultSecret doesn't work when in a function
I have a .psm1 module file that has a few helper functions for the run.ps1 script.
In one of the functions, I'm accessing Azure Key Vault to grab a connection secret; this is where the run.ps1 seems to hang.
The managed identity is setup and has access permissions to the vault. I get the [warning] message about accessing a secret but the run.ps1 just STOPS completely at this point, no error.
I tried copying the manual block of code to the top of my run.ps1 script and it works as intended.
Here's a snippet of the code copied into run.ps1 that works.
$applicationId = 'abc123'
$securePassword = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "KV-SANDBOX" -Name "ConnectionSecret"
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword.SecretValue

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount  -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId 'a1b2c3'

Is this a scoping issue? I'm not finding anything about keyvault and functions.
What I tried:

Running the scripts locally works
I tried dot-sourcing the functions in a .ps1 file (exhibits problem)
I tried creating a \Modules\ folder with a .psm1 file with all function (exhibits problem)
Copying the function code to the run.ps1 directly works properly


Can you share the code which is causing the issue in function app? @James

In order to use Get-AzKeyVaultSecret and Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount in function app, you need to add below modules in requirements.psd1 file.
@{
    'Az.KeyVault' = '4.*'
    'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt' = '1.*'
}

Then increase the function timeout in host.json if you are consumption plan which will give the function app enough time to install the modules.
{
    "version":"2.0",
    "managedDependency":{
        "Enabled":true
    },
    "extensionBundle":{
        "id":"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle","version":"[4.*, 5.0.0)"
    },
    "functionTimeout":"00:09:00"
}

I am using below given code to establish connection with Power BI using service principal.
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$applicationId = 'c266*****ea5'
$securePassword = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "afreenKvvv" -Name "ConnectionSecret"
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword.SecretValue

try {
    Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId '932*****f6d'
    Write-Host "Connection to Power BI established successfully."
    
    $body = "Power BI connection established successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to connect to Power BI."
    
    $body = "Failed to connect to Power BI. Error: $_"
}

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})

By following the above given steps, you should get the expected response.

